# Delete Not working in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

// GET: /Product/Delete/5

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();
        //return View(data.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == id));
        return View(res);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Product/Delete/5
   // [HttpPost]
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    **public ActionResult Delete(Product producttodelete)**
    {

        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here
            var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == producttodelete.ProductID select r).FirstOrDefault();
           // var productto = data.Products.Single(p => p.ProductID == producttodelete.ProductID);
            data.Products.DeleteObject(res);
            data.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here in the line "producttodelete" i am not getting any values it is cuming null.Rather than create,details,edit are working fine.... only delete not working.......I tried a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using strongly typed views, have you tried:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, Product productToDelete)
{
    try
    {
        var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();
        data.Products.DeleteObject(res);
        data.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

... or if you are not using strongly typed views:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();
        data.Products.DeleteObject(res);
        data.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In either case, you need to provide an `id` parameter which you can then use to get your object from your datastore. The default route mapping in MVC2 (in Global.asax.cs) will take the ID from the post URL and map it to this parameter for you.

Comment: while crossing data.savechanges i got this error("An error occured while updating the entries. see the inner exception for details) in catch block

Comment: @Karthik so what's the inner exception?

Comment: public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();return View(res);}
      
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();
             data.Products.DeleteObject(res);
             data.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");}
            catch
            {return View();}
        }

Comment: i dont know what is inner exception pls check it and tell

Comment: it is exactly cuming in data.savechanges()

Comment: @Karthik you'll need to use Visual Studio to inspect the exception to find out more about what's going wrong. If you're not sure about how to do this, RTM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

why not just get the id like you were in the rest instead of trying to get the whole model?  it seems like you're just selecting using the id anyway.  try this:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {

            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();
               // var productto = data.Products.Single(p => p.ProductID == producttodelete.ProductID);
                data.Products.DeleteObject(res);
                data.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: AS per u reply both the functions are same it say the error "Type '.....'already defines a member called 'Delete'with the same parameter types

Comment: [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)

Comment: public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();return View(res);}
      
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {var res = (from r in data.Products where r.ProductID == id select r).FirstOrDefault();
             data.Products.DeleteObject(res);
             data.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index");}
            catch
            {return View();}
        }